# hacer una consulta de variable generada dentro de otra variable

Tags: php, mysql

tengo esta consulta para ver si el archivo existe dentro de una carpeta llamadas _sellos

```
<?php 
  $nombre_fichero = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\_sellos\7992-2018-E01-sellos.pdf'; 
  if (file_exists($nombre_fichero)) {
```

este nombre  7992-2018-E01-sellos.pdf se obtiene del resultado de 3 consultas, esta manera:

7992 = `<?php echo substr($contrato['numero_contrato'],0,4) ;?>`

2018 = `<?php echo $contrato['year']; ?>`

E01= `<?php echo substr($contrato['numero_contrato'],-3) ; ?>-sellos.pdf`

quedando algo asi para generar el nombre a comparar:

> ```
> <?php $nombre_fichero = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\_sellos\<?php echo
> substr($contrato['numero_contrato'],0,4) ;?>-<?php echo
> $contrato['year']; ?>-<?php echo
> substr($contrato['numero_contrato'],-3) ; ?>-sellos.pdf';
> ```

claramente esto no funciona por que incluyo el ?php y ?, no tengo idea de como hacerlo dentro de la variable sin incluir el ?php y ?

Al probar la respuesta con el siguiente código deja de funcionar el query

```
$var1 = substr($contrato['numero_contrato'],0,4); 
$var2 = $contrato['year']; 
$var3 = substr($contrato['numero_contrato'],-3);

$nombre_fichero = "C:\xampp\htdocs\_sellos\\$var1-$var2-$var3-sellos.pdf";

if (file_exists($nombre_fichero)) {
    echo "El fichero $nombre_fichero existe"; 
} else {
    echo "El fichero $nombre_fichero no existe";
}
```

Comment: Si te entiendo bien ¿lo que quieres es almacenar esto `<?php echo substr($contrato['numero_contrato'],0,4) ;?>` en una variable?

Comment: es convertir este nombre 7992-2018-E01-sellos.pdf en una variable para incluirlo en la consulta original: C:\xampp\htdocs\atenea18\_sellos\7992-2018-E01-sellos.pdf pero como ya es una variable no puedo usar a apertura de un <php

Comment: el <?php $nombre_fichero = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\_sellos\ (esto que continua es una variable)-sellos.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te va a funcionar por que estas llamando mal los datos, estas confundido con los conceptos básicos de PHP.

La funcion echo es para presentar datos por pantalla, no debes usarla para generar variables.

Como solución podrías crear variables para cada string y luego generar tu $variable que contenga la dirección del archivo, algo así:

```
$var1 = substr($contrato['numero_contrato'],0,4);
$var2 = $contrato['year'];
$var3 = substr($contrato['numero_contrato'],-3);

$nombre_fichero = "C:\xampp\htdocs\_sellos\\$var1-$var2-$var3-sellos.pdf";
```

Nótese el uso de ""(comillas dobles) en vez de ''(comillas simples), esto para que las variables no sean tomadas como cadenas, sino que tomen el valor que tiene asignado.

Comment: gracias pero la variable $var1 no la toma aparece el nombre esta debo encerrarla en comillas?? aparece esto: C: mpp\htdocs\_sellos\$var1-2018-E01-sellos.pdf

Comment: Ahora edito la respuesta, el problema es que al tener \ salta el caracter $

Comment: bueno puedo cambiar el origen del archivo y colocarle un - delante

Comment: No es necesario, solo coloca \\ antes de $var1, ya edite la respuesta.

Comment: he editado al final de la pregunta ya que el query deja de funcionar, no detecta si el archivo existe o no, indica que el archivo: El fichero C: mpp\htdocs\_sellos\7992-2018-E01-sellos.pdf no existe.

Comment: Que te imprime $nombre_fichero?

Comment: El fichero 'C: mpp\htdocs\_sellos\7992-2018-E01-sellos.pdf' no existe y el archivo esta en la carpeta con el nombre : 7992-2018-E01-sellos.pdf

Comment: he agregado a la funcion \\ y ahora imprime la ruta completa del archivo pero sigue sin indicar que existe el archivo  : El fichero 'C:\xampp\htdocs\_sellos\7992-2018-E01-sellos.pdf' no existe

Comment: En tu pregunta original la direccion del archivo es: `C:\xampp\htdocs\_sellos\7992-2018-E01-sellos.pdf`, y ahora tienes `C:\xampp\htdocs_sellos\7992-2018-E01-sellos.pdf`, cual es la correcta?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\sellos

Comment: El problema es ese, no estas apuntando bien la dirección, ahora la direccion que dices es: `C:\xampp\htdocs\sellos` no `C:\xampp\htdocs\_sellos`

Comment: vale si ya me di de cuenta disculpa la pregunta